# Why is there no "date" shorthand of System.DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Such as `int`, `long`, `ushort`, `uint`, `short`, etc.

Why isn't there a short hand for `System.DateTime`?

Comment: What other type with a shorthand alias in C# is not directly assignable with a literal expression?

Comment: It's still a `struct`.. that doesn't cut it?

Comment: This is probably the sort of question that only Eric Lippert can answer. Related: Why are there no `DateTime` literals?

Comment: @Michael: I'm always interested in what Eric's got to say :)

Comment: There is a `Date` alias in VB.NET (to cater for VB6 users). No similar reason to add it to C#.

Comment: If you want, you could add a `using date = System.DateTime;` in your code files.

Comment: That's besides the point, and a horrible hack in my opinion.

Comment: @Nico There are a lot of structs in the BCL, only a handful have aliases. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660933(v=pandp.20).aspx#_Default_Aliases_and

Comment: @Michael Liu: Because `System.DateTime` isn't even a type defined by the language specification. It's in the BCL, not a built-in type.

Comment: Maybe because it sort of changes the meaning of the `DateTime` object? Which would it be, `date` or `time`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Many types are associated with "shorthand" keywords in C#; for example, `System.Int32` can also be written `int` and `System.String` can be written `string`. Why isn't there a shorthand for `System.DateTime`?

Before I answer that question -- or rather, fail to answer it -- let's first note the types that have shorthands in C#. They are

```
object 
string 
sbyte byte short ushort int uint long ulong 
char 
bool 
decimal double float
```

Let me first address some of the other answers.

Mystere Man notes correctly that several of these keywords come from C; C has `int` and the rather wordy `unsigned int`, `double`, and a few others. However C most notably does not have `bool`, `long`, `decimal`, `object` or `string`.

I think we can reasonably say that one justification for including keywords `int` and `char` and so on is so that users familiar with C and C++ can be productive quickly in C#. The aim here is for the keywords to be familiar to C programmers, but it was absolutely not the aim for these keywords to have the same semantics as they do in C. C does not specify the size of any of those, for example, and strongly encourages `int` to be the "natural size" of the machine. C# does specify the exact size and range of each type.

So I do not think we can reasonably say that the justification for *not* having a shorthand for `System.DateTime` is because there was none in C. There was no `string` or `decimal` in C either.

Jason notes that `DateTime` is not "part of the C# language" and therefore does not have a keyword. But that is thoroughly begging the question! The question is essentially then "OK, so then why is DateTime not a part of the C# language?" Answering a question in a manner which requires a question of equal difficulty to be answered is called "begging the question", and this question has been thoroughly begged.

It is instructive to consider what are the "fundamental" types. All of the types that have keywords in C# are "very special" in some way, *except for `decimal`*. That is, the underlying runtime has special behaviour built into it for `object`, obviously, as it is the universal base type. `string` could have simply been an array of `char`, but it is not; strings are special. (Because they can be interned, they can be constant, they can exist in metadata, and so on.)  The integral and binary floating point types all have special handling built into the framework for their operations.

But `System.Decimal` is just another struct type; it's 128 bits of integers and a whole lot of user-defined operators. Anyone could implement their own decimal arithmetic type if they wanted to. But "blessing" `System.Decimal` by making it a part of the C# language means that even though its conversions are implemented as methods, we treat them as *built in conversions*, not as *user-defined conversions*.

So `decimal` really is an odd one. It is not a "fundamental" type of the runtime, but it is a keyword.

This brings up an interesting point though. *System.IntPtr* and *System.UIntPtr* *are* fundamental types of the runtime. They are the "pointer sized integer" types; they are what C means by `int` and `unsigned int`.  Even though these types are fundamental to the .NET runtime's type system, they do *not* get blessed with a keyword.

Thus, we can reject the argument that only "fundamental" types get a keyword. There is a non-fundamental type that got a keyword, and a fundamental type that did not get a keyword, so there is no one-to-one relationship between fundamental types and types that got a keyword.

Tigran opines that the choices were "historical", which is correct but does not actually answer the question.

Hans Passant notes correctly that clearly specifying the size and range of an int helps make the language behaviour consistent even as the native integer size changes, and notes that `DateTime` has already been designed to be "future proof". Though this analysis is correct, it does not explain why decimal is made a keyword. There's no fear that the "native decimal size" of a machine is going to change in the future. Moreover, the C# language already notes that though a double will always consume 8 bytes of storage, there is no requirement that C# restrict the processing of doubles to a mere 64 bits of precision; in fact C# programs often do double arithmetic in 80 or more bits of precision.

I don't think any of these answers successfully address the question. So let's return to the question:

> Many types are associated with "shorthand" keywords in C#; for example, `System.Int32` can also be written `int` and `System.String` can be written `string`. Why isn't there a shorthand for `System.DateTime`?

The answer to this question is the same as the answer to every question of the form "why does C# not implement a feature I like?" The answer is:  **we are not required to provide a justification for not implementing a feature.** Features are *expensive*, and, as Raymond Chen often points out, are *unimplemented by default*. It takes no work to leave an unimplemented feature unimplemented.

The feature suggestion is not *unreasonable* at all; Visual Basic in some sense treats `DateTime` as a special type, and C# could too if we decided that it was worthwhile doing that work.  But not every reasonable feature gets implemented.

Comment: "However C most notably does not have bool, long, decimal, object or string" -- actually, C does have bool and long.

Comment: @lukas C89 doesn't, C99 and the new C11 do.

Comment: @hvd in C99 they added _Bool but it's not widely used.

Comment: @lukas C99 also provides `bool` as a synonym in the standard library header `<stdbool.h>`. As for how widely it's used, that's mostly because C99 as a whole isn't widely used.

Comment: Excellent answer Eric! Wouldn't you consider adding compiler extensibility to Roslyn? At least you would change the default answer to this kind of question (and I've seen you answer _tons_ of questions like this) to: "you can do it yourself" :-)

Comment: @Jordão: The purpose of Roslyn is *code analysis*, not *language extensibility*.

Comment: @EricLippert +1 well structured and concise, maybe a little wordie but does a great job of explaining.

Answer (score 0):

The aliases for Int32, Int64, etcetera in the C# language exist to make the language future-proof.  To still make it relevant when everybody has a 256-bit core in their desktop machine.  With a wholelotta hemming and hawing to *really* make that happen, the amount of C# code that's around that implicitly *assumes* that int is 32-bits is rife.  But not actually that hard, I moved chunks of code I wrote from CP/M to MS-DOS to Windows 3.x to Windows NT with surprisingly little effort.

That's not an issue for DateTime.  It is future-proof until the year 10,000.  I trust and hope that by then the machine understands what I meant, not what I typed :)

Comment: C# defines `int` as `System.Int32`. A conforming C# implementation cannot make it a 64-bit type.

Comment: also the `string` has a shorthand, but it's a reference type, so..I think there is no *true* answer on this. The matter of choice of framework designers in regard of history of the CS.

Comment: Ahhh, are you still right 30 years from now?  Are you sure?  Or are you just really uncomfortable about it?  Votes suggests everybody is :)

Comment: I don't think this is correct; in fact I think I remember a blog post from Lippert (maybe someone else's) that specifically mentioned this not being the reason at all.

Comment: I don't think so. Do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, if hard guarantees by the C# spec are dropped in future versions of C#, code will break. Duh. :)

Comment: Yes if that's the reason then I'm better of _not_ using the aliases in general... Insofar that one cares about his/her code in 30 yrs

Comment: @Tigran - the string type is an excellent example as well.  Right now it maps to System.String, a type that stores the utf-16 encoded version of a string.  Widely ignored in C# code, nobody ever checks if string[] is a surrogate.  The *perfect* encoding for a string is utf-32, 4 billion characters.  Thirty years from now with machines having a petabyte of memory, is System.String still relevant?

Comment: Is C# or .NET even relevant thirty years from now?

Comment: @HansPassant A surrogate pair is about as easy or difficult to handle properly as a combining character, and combining characters still exist even in utf-32, so utf-32 doesn't really add all that much IMO. (But that's a whole other discussion, really.)

Comment: @hvd: and here I was thinking that utf-32 has per character fixed storage size

Comment: @sixfeetsix Well, it does, it's just that the concept of a "character" can be less than useful if it disagrees with what the user considers one :)

Answer (score 0):

Noone other then someone from BCL/.NET team can give a true answer, but I think it's simply *historical reason*, like for the types `char`, `float`... and their "extensions"  (like `int`->`uint` matnioned in the comment) there is, for others no.

I could make the same question for other `.NET Framework type` types, cause we have shorthand for `string` in .NET, but `string` is a *reference* type. So...

Hope I'm explained.

Comment: `string` is not a BCL type. It's defined by the language specification.

Comment: @Jason: ok, I will correct to .NET Framework type. My point is: if you a language designer which type you will let to have a shorthand, which not? It's a matter of choice. *Imo* there is no any strong logic behind, other then something *historical*, something that we developers are familiar with to see in any other API. Am I wrong?