# Why the DateTime is not a predefined type?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

The `System` namespace in the .NET Framework contains many important types that are not predefined by C# e.g. `DateTime`.

Could you please explain, Why `DateTime` is not a predefined type?

Comment: What do you mean by pre-defined? That it has no alias like `System.Int32` -> `int`?

Comment: I think you mean primitive not pre-defined?

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you're asking. What support do you expect C# (as a lanugage) to have for `DateTime`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Me too wondering how very unclear question got two upvotes :(

Comment: Actually, a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058883/why-is-there-no-date-shorthand-of-system-datetime-in-c) has already been asked and [extensively answered by Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10063923/1430156), where he states *Thus, we can reject the argument that only "fundamental" types get a keyword.* as one of his sub-conclusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should it? It isn't a [basic type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx), it is a [`struct` of various basic types](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b).

Only the types minimally necessary to support the CLR are included, nothing more. There is no need for a lot of types to be declared on the CLR level, it only makes it more complicated and makes maintaining the CLR on various platforms a hell.

Since the type is built on top of the CLR, it can benefit from the abstraction brought by the CLR.

Comment: Arguably, the same applies to `string`, which could be implemented using an array of `char`, i.e. just as a class of various basic types.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: True, but with a very specific implementation, I guess for performance reasons. See the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c).

Comment: Sure, I've just checked in ILSpy before writing my comment, hence I wrote "could be implemented" - in any case, the specific implementation does not seem to be required by the C# language specification. The C# `string` keyword is pointed out as an alias for the `System.String` class, but nothing is mentioned about that class as such having to be "special" in any way, or at least not more special than other classes that do not have C# keyword aliases, such as `Exception`.

Comment: can we create a alias for our custom class ??

Comment: Meanwhile, I have found an interesting [answer by Eric Lippert on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10063923/1430156), where he states *Thus, we can reject the argument that only "fundamental" types get a keyword.* as one of his sub-conclusions, as there is at least an exception to that rule.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I read the question from a slightly different angle, but that is a nice post indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [types that have aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) (like `System.Int32` -> `int`) are, as you can see, also "predefined" in the system namespace. By that logic, DateTime is predefined, it just doesn't have an alias.

Answer (score 2):

Because it isn't in the language specification:

> 4.1 Value types
>
> [...] C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types. The simple types are identified through reserved words.
>
> - *simple-type*:
>
>   - *numeric-type*
>   - bool
> - *numeric-type*:
>
>   - *integral-type*
>   - *floating-point-type*
>   - decimal

As for "why", you'll need one of the language's designers.  Why would you expect it to? Why `DateTime`, but not `Point`?

Comment: My assumption has always been "because its made of several seperable components, so isn't a primitive" but I guess you could make that argument about string being made up of many char, but I think the assumption is reasonable ?

Comment: Any explanation can be reasonable, but OP didn't give any, hence we cannot properly answer that. So my question to OP: what does he think a predefined type is, what does he expect from it and why should `DateTime` be one?