# DateTime c# is predefined? but only in Rider?

Tags: c#

The book C# 12 in a Nutshell and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797818/why-the-datetime-is-not-a-predefined-type) clearly say:

> The System namespace in the .NET Framework contains many important
> types that are not predefined by C# e.g. DateTime.

However, running those very two lines in JetBrains Rider works

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now);
```

[image]

This does not work on online websites to run C# code (like https://rextester.com/ or https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/online-compiler/).

Why is there a difference? It seems the `using System` is there by default in Rider?

Comment: I know this is not vital in the day-to-day life of a Software Engineer but I'm still wondering why there is a difference to see how things really work "under the hood"

Comment: This works just fine on said website - unless you also removed the `using System;` at the top, as what you're typing in Rider is a "Top-level statements"-style `Program.cs` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements) with implicit usings (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-csharp-10/) automatically importing the `System` namespace for you.

Comment: I had removed the `using System;` at the top yes to mimic what I was seeing in Rider. Turns out the ImplicitUsings were putting them back. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the using statements/directives in .NET 6 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738921/where-are-the-using-statements-directives-in-net-6-and-above)

Comment: Yes it does I had been on it but gave up because I was not understanding anything but now that I'm re-reading it it did! (I'm a beginner in programming so I realised too late I guess)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project is likely using **Implicit Usings**. This is a feature of the SDK that will, as its name suggests, implicitly include `using` statements for the most common namespaces of the project type. To check if this feature is enabled, see if this is included in the `.csproj` file:

`<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>`

The base SDK will include the following namespaces implicity with this feature:

```
System
System.Collections.Generic
System.IO
System.Linq
System.Net.Http
System.Threading
System.Threading.Tasks
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#implicit-using-directives

Comment: Worth mention another possibility - [global using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier) (C# 10+), where `using global System;` is required in just one (any?) cs-file of the project.